# How to Pass Selected text from a list to controller to do some operation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have just started learning Angular JS and trying bto write a simple calc program which can select the operation from a selection box and do the operation on two numbers.

I am able to do this using buttons but not able to do this using a selection box.

Please suggest on below lines of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="Jscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>Hello Angular</h1>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  1st Number : <input type="text" ng-model="num1"><br/>
  2nd Number : <input type="text" ng-model="num2">

        <p><select ng-model="operator">
            <option>+</option>
            <option>*</option>
            <option>-</option>
            <option>/</option>
         </select></p>

  <input type="button" ng-click="add(num1,num2)" value="ADD">        <input type="button" ng-click="multiply(num1,num2)" value="Multiply">

  <input type="button" ng-click="subtract(num1,num2)" value="Subtract">
  <input type="button" ng-click="divide(num1,num2)" value="Divide"><br/> <br/> <br/>

  Sum : {{result}}
  <div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the corresponding JS File:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) 
{
    $scope.add = function (num1, num2) 
    {
        $scope.result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
    }

    $scope.multiply = function (num1, num2) {
        $scope.result = parseInt(num1) * parseInt(num2);
    }

    $scope.subtract = function (num1, num2) {
        $scope.result = parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num2);
    }

    $scope.divide = function (num1, num2) {
        $scope.result = parseInt(num1) / parseInt(num2);
    }

});
```

Now instead of button I want to do the operation on selection of dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-change` a.e.: `<select ng-model="operator" ng-change="onChange()">`and:

```
$scope.onChange = function(){

      switch ($scope.operator) {
        case '+':
          $scope.result = parseInt($scope.num1) + parseInt($scope.num2);
          break;
        case '-':
          $scope.result = parseInt($scope.num1) - parseInt($scope.num2);
          break;
      case '/':
           $scope.result = parseInt($scope.num1) / parseInt($scope.num2);
          break;   
      case '*':
           $scope.result = parseInt($scope.num1) * parseInt($scope.num2);
          break;       

        default:
          // code
      }

    }
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6oCjfTVKswewm2i0Qzx?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: @user2519971 you welcome to up-vote/Accept if it was helpful thanks